# Why does adding a 1px border improve printing?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I am producing a 20+ page report in HTML and wish to control the page breaks, margins etc carefully.

I have one particular DIV that is repeated many times and contains various floated DIVs, SVGs etc. This is styled with `page-break-before: always;`, and works well.

However when printing in Chrome (and only seen in print preview and the final hard copy) the height of the DIVs appears to vary randomly, with other paras split across pages. It's as if Chrome gets confused about the height of one element and then carries this mistake on, causing other elements to split across page breaks.

I can fix this by putting `border:1px solid white;` on the DIV. Why does this work?

I guess this is something to do with `box-sizing` and collapsing margins or is it just a quirk?

And is there a better, more universal way to achieve this? I've tried `box-sizing: border-box` but this doesn't correct it like the white border does.

Comment: are you sure the floats are cleared for those elements?

Comment: Thanks Jonas - this did the trick. Kicking myself.